# grouping dataframes in pandas efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe in pandas where there's a unique index (`employee`) for each row and also a group label `type`:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"employee": ["a", "b", "c", "d"], "type": ["X", "Y", "Y", "Y"], "value": [10,20,30,40]})
df = df.set_index("employee")
```

I want to group the employees by `type` and then calculate a statistic for each type. How can I do this and get a final dataframe which is `type x statistic`, for example `type x (mean of types)`? I tried using `groupby`:

```
g = df.groupby(lambda x: df.ix[x]["type"])
result = g.mean()
```

this is inefficient since it references the index `ix` of `df` for each row - is there a better way?

Comment: why not just use `g = df.groupby("type")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like @sza says, you can use:

```
In [11]: g = df.groupby("type")

In [12]: g.mean()
Out[12]:
      value
type
X        10
Y        30
```

*see the [groupby docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) for more...*